# How can I get Name of all apex class having api version less than 36 in my org?

Tags: apex, trigger

How can I get Name of all apex class having api version less than 36 in my org? We need to upgrade classes having older api version.Please guide us regarding that.

Comment: this is the query to get all apex class and api version. SELECT name,ApiVersion FROM ApexClass WHERE ApiVersion < 36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better if you create a view in Apex class section in your org.
There you can filter the classes by applying filter based on ApiVersion of classes.

[image]

Other then this you can perform Query also on [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) Object.
The following Query would work for you:

```
Select Apiversion,Name from ApexClass where Apiversion<36
```